# How can i join multiple mysql table without knowing the primary key and foreign key of the tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have a requirement of joining the multiple tables in mysql and mongodb but i don't know the primary key and foriegn key of the table and how should i know which kind of join to make means(inner join, left join, right join). Is there any way i can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your question pertain to sql-server and oracle? Either add that to your question or remove the extraneous tags.

Comment: If this is for MySQL and MongoDB, why have you tagged php, SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: So you are basically saying you have absolutely no idea how the tables in your database are related to each other?

Comment: On a different note, if *you* don't know what the join criteria is, how on earth are a bunch of strangers on the internet supposed to know?

Comment: yes it is the client database and i have to get the data on the fly.

Comment: @Amitif if your clients won't tell you about their database structure, how are you supposed to work with it? Nevermind some *strangers on the internet* like us?

Comment: I know this is silly question but requirement came to us. Just checking is their any solution availalble or not.

Comment: if you don't know the relationship of the data, you cannot build a query on the data's relationship. Much like if you were asked to separate a bunch of people into their respective families, however, you don't know their names, addresses, etc, and they are completely covered up (so you can't even tell gender, or ethnicity). You'd be completely guessing.

Comment: You could work it out by interrogating each individual, however, you're going to therefore need to do the same for the data. The easier answer would be to have the details of the relationships. Go back to your client and ask them for it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use UNION ALL for joining multiple tables

Select * from table1 UNION ALL
Select * from table2 UNION ALL
Select * from table3 ;

Make sure that there are equal number of columns in all tables

Comment: answer makes sense for same column across all tables, but in our case table columns will vary.

Comment: This will not help at all to solve the OPs Problem, it will just throw all of the data avaiable into one single and unnessasary big query / data blob.